# how to send data from the function to angular material dialog?

Tags: angular-material, modal-dialog, angular8

I got the data from clicking the row of the table. Now I got the data, then how do I send data to the dialog component and use it?

```
    rowClicked(data) {
        console.log("row data");
        console.log(data);
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DashboardTableDialogComponent, {
            scrollStrategy: new NoopScrollStrategy(),
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
            console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your component, where you are creating an instance of Dialog Component, we need to send data to Dialog as below:

`const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DashboardTableDialogComponent, {
            scrollStrategy: new NoopScrollStrategy(),
            data : data //This is where you can pass data to your dialog component.
        });`

Inside the DashboardTableDialogComponent, Get the data via Dependency Injection as shown below:

`private data:any;
constructor ( @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, ...)
{
   this.dataFromParent = data;
}`

Hope this should help your problem.